# Azure Function with TimerTrigger shows execution count of 0 despite function running

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-monitoring

I have a function app with a single, timer-triggered function running in MS Azure.

**Background**

- The timer runs every 15 seconds with the following NCRONTAB expression: `*/15 * * * * *`
- Clicking on the "Monitor" tab in the Azure portal shows many successful executions on the expected interval (every 15 seconds)
- I have proof that the function is indeed running as expected (behavior is to call a web API on each execution, and I can see from the other side of that API that it is indeed being called).

**Problem**

- In the Azure portal on the "Overview" tab of the overall function app, the metric widget showing "Function Execution Count" constantly shows 0 executions.
- I have attempted to set up an Azure Monitor Alerting Rule in which I am notified any time the single function in this function app has not run at least 15 times in the last 5 minutes. The alert rule is in a persistent state of being activated/fired, presumably since the overall function execution count is always 0.

**Question**

- What might be causing the "Function Execution Count" metric not to update?
- If it showing 0 is the expected behavior, what is the best practice for implementing an alert for a specific function on a timer trigger not firing as expected (or erroring)?

Comment: I am having the same issue. It will be very helpful if you post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the workaround I did to get the Metrics in Azure Function Portal Overview Tab and the alerts as per the required condition if met:**

***Firstly, I checked my Timer Trigger (`*/15 * * * * *`) Azure Function App running successful in locally for every 15 seconds:***

[image]

***Configured the Azure Functions to Application Insights in Visual Studio and then Published to the Azure Portal Function App.***

[image]

***All the metrics, Function Execution Count, Memory working Set, Server Request Time, Server Response Times are recorded while running the Azure Function App Timer Trigger at every 15 seconds as you can see in the screenshot below:***

[image: FunctionOverviewMetricsTab]

---

> what is the best practice for implementing an alert for a specific function on a timer trigger not firing as expected (or erroring)?

**To create a Alert:**

**Step 1:**
Go to the Associated **Application Insights** Resource with the **Function App** > Select **Alerts** from **Monitoring** Section.

**Step 2:**

***Click on Create Menu > Alert Rule > Type as Count in the Search Bar and Select the Metric named as `<YourFunctionName> Count`***

[image]

***After Selecting the Metric, Make your requirement condition to get alerts as you can see the screenshot below that I made alert rule to the condition for every 5 minutes if  function count is below < 15 times.***

[image]

***After clicking on done, you will see like:***

[image]

[image]

***You'll get the alert rule creation successful notification in the notification bar:***

[image]

***Run the Function and check the Alerts Page from Monitoring Section in the Azure Application Insights Resource.***

[image]

***To get more details like Function execution count per minute and the timings, Click on the color bar as you can see the screenshot below when you clicked on it:***

[image]

**Reference: [Monitor Via Application Insights - Alert Rules](https://dev.to/kenakamu/monitor-application-via-application-insights-part-1-set-rule-and-action-45k4)**

**Note:**

> my question of why for a function app I previous deployed, the "Function Execution Count" is always ever 0.

Please check few steps given below:

- Make Sure You have configured the Application Insights while publishing the Function App as shown in 2nd Image.
- In the Azure Portal Function App > Under Application Insights option, You have to see this kind of Message: `Your app is connected to App Insights Resource: <yourFunctionName>`
  [image]
- If that message not visible or you can cross check by doing like this:
  Azure Portal > Function App > Application Insights under Settings > Select the option `Change your Resource > Select Existing Resource > Select Your Subscription - Then all the function apps will be appeared in the table, select the deployed function app which you want to track the logs and metrics`.

[image]

- Make Sure all the settings under Configuration like `AzureWebJobsStorage` and `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTION`  are having same storage account connection string/values and the `AppInsights Instrumentation Key` and its `connection string` values verify by checking the Application Insights Resources associated with that function app.

[image]

- Also, Please visit this [Msft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/analyze-telemetry-data#view-telemetry-in-application-insights) about enabling the Telemetry in Application Insights.

#### Updated Answer:

**Before the workaround for Azure Functions Python Stack - Application Insights, there are some limitations:**

- For the parameters like locations, runtime stack, OS, publish type, resource group or subscription, Application Insights code-less monitoring isn't supported with your selections of the mentioned parameters while creating Azure Function App in the Portal.

**Example:** I Selected South India location where Consumption and Premium Hosting plans are not available for my Subscription or the selected Location. If  I need for that location, I need to configure through AI SDK as shown below:

[image: AIRestrictiononlocations]

**Here is the workaround I did to get the Metrics in Azure Function Portal Overview Tab and the alerts as per the required condition if met:**

***Firstly, I checked my Timer Trigger (`*/15 * * * * *`) Azure Function App running successful in locally for every 15 seconds:***

[image]

- And Then Created the Function App in Azure Portal (West US2) along with the integration of Application Insights and deployed to Azure from VS Code.
- After running the Function from the Azure Portal, All the metrics, Function Execution Count, Memory working Set, Server Request Time, Server Response Times are recorded while running the Azure Function App Timer Trigger at every 15 seconds as you can see in screenshot below:

[image]

---

> what is the best practice for implementing an alert for a specific function on a timer trigger not firing as expected (or erroring)?

**To create a Alert:**

**Step 1:**
Go to the Associated **Application Insights** Resource with the **Function App** > Select **Alerts** from **Monitoring** Section.

**Step 2:**

***Click on Create Menu > Alert Rule > Type as Count in the Search Bar and Select the Metric named as `<YourFunctionName> Count`***

***After Selecting the Metric, Make your requirement condition to get alerts as you can see the screenshot below that I made alert rule to the condition for every 5 minutes if  function count is below < 15 times.***

[image]

***Run the Function and check the Alerts Page from Monitoring Section in the Azure Application Insights Resource.***

[image]

[image]

---

**Code used in Azure Functions Python Stack:**

**host.json:**

```py
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
"applicationInsights": {
"samplingSettings": {
"isEnabled": true,
"excludedTypes": "Request"
}
}
},
"extensionBundle": {
"id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
"version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
}
}
```

**requirements.txt**

azure-functions

**local.settings.json:**

```py
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "<YourStorageAccountConnectionString",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
}
}
```

***init*.py**

```py
import  datetime
import  logging
import  azure.functions  as  func

def  main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

if  mytimer.past_due:

logging.info('The timer is past due!')
logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

**function.json:**

```py
{
"scriptFile": "__init__.py",
"bindings": [
{
"name": "mytimer",
"type": "timerTrigger",
"direction": "in",
"schedule": "*/15 * * * * *"
}
]
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, however it doesn't answer my question of why for a function app I previous deployed, the "Function Execution Count" is always ever 0.

Comment: Please check you have configured the Correct Application Insights Resource in Visual Studio from publishing the Function App!

Comment: Hi @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT, thank you for your help! I have been able to get the alerting running as needed by setting up an alert within my App Insights resource specific to the individual function. However, even after re-selecting an App Insights resource for my Function App, "Function Execution Count" on the Function App Overview tab is still always showing 0, unless I manually trigger the function from within the Code/Test panel of the Function App.

Comment: Additionally, I used VS Code to deploy, not Visual Studio, so I didn't have the ability to verify those metrics prior to deploying.

Comment: Hi @George, You can configure the Azure Application Insights resource to the function app in VS Code also through Azure Extension before Publishing/deploying the App!

Comment: I have verified `AzureWebJobsStorage` is a valid connection string to a storage account I established when deploying. My function app does not have a configuration variable for `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTION`

Comment: Which Stack [.NET, Python, JS, Java, etc] you're using in Azure Function?

Comment: Thanks - yes, sorry, I confirm I deployed app insights with the function app in VS code. I misread the question. I am using Python 3.9.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242093/discussion-between-harikrishnarajoli-mt-and-george).